# Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0. I have integrated the user login with xenforo but after integreating when i am doing any operation like add, edit, delete the view is not redirecting, `$this->redirect` is not working.

I am getting this error :

> Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator in ......

Thanks

Comment: That's a warning, not an error...

Comment: So....don't use `is_a()` and use `instanceof` instead.  There's a reason why warning messages are generated: so that people can read them.

Comment: is_a was un-deprecated, as it allows this the instanceof operator doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

This function was deprecated in 5.0, but since there are valid usecases for it, not covered by `instanceof`, it was re-introduced in 5.3. I suggest you upgrade your installation of PHP.

Comment: What were the use cases for `is_a()` that `instanceof` doesn't cover?

Comment: The input being a string. As in `is_a($foo, 'Thing')`, which is different from `is_a($foo, Thing)`. The former is a dynamically bound symbol, and the latter a statically bound one.

Comment: My version of PHP is already 5.3.13, but why does it still have that error?

Comment: @ElsonSolano Are you certain? You might have a different version of PHP in your web server (mod_php) than your cli. Try outputting `phpinfo()` to check the version number.

Answer (score 0):

So since is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the [instanceof operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) instead.

```
if($object instanceof stdClass)
{
    ...
}
```